# min-width doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div that able to expand the width when user input the text

I tried to set 
  width:100%; 
  max-width:600px; 
  min-width:300px;

But some how this div just stay at 600px, is that any way to keep the width stay at 300px and able to expand to 600px base on the length of the content?

Really appreciate if you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Setting the div to `display: inline-block` allows it to shift width depending on the contents.

Otherwise, as a block level element, the div will take up 100% of it's containing element (or however wide you set `max-width`).

Here's a an example:

http://cssdesk.com/Bwp8E

Comment: the link is broken, can you provide a full example in your answer?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```css
width: auto;
max-width: 600px;
min-width: 300px;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just update the "min-width" page on MDN with this information:

*In some browsers, on iOS, a `<button>` element in its native (default) configuration will not respond to `min-width`.    This problem is due to native buttons.  A `<span>` inside a native button will exhibit the same problem, despite having `display:inline-block` set.  When changes are made to other style parameters and the browser is forced to abandon the native button, the `min-width` setting takes affect.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the div or space your working on isn't: `position:fixed;`

It needs to be something like: `position: relative;` or `position:absolute;`